# Laravel 5.3: Best way to retrieve data between dates and group them in weeks?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys I need some SQL advice here...
Lets say I have 1000 rows of data from the past 8 weeks. Each row has a `DATETIME` field and I want to pull the last 3 weeks, group the data by week 1, week 2 and week 3. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share with example of 10 rows, and what your expected output ?

Comment: 1) tag your database, 2) What you mean by week? any 7 day ?

Comment: What you have tries so far

Comment: do you want to group it to get the aggregate? because there are 2 possible difference approach. First is to group it in the database. Second is to group it after the data is retrieved from the database using Laravel Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). Assuming the `Record` model and `created_at` attribute:

```
$records=Record::where('created_at', '<' ,Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeeks(3))->get() ->groupBy(function($date) {
                return Carbon\Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W');
            });
```

and then,

```
foreach($records as $week=>$record)
{
   echo $week;   // gives week 1, week 2 , week 3..
   foreach($record as $r)
   {
    echo $r;
   }
}
```